# Pivot Table created with Power Pivot does not include all data

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery, powerpivot

I have a pivot table which is created with Power Pivot and Power Query that needs to be updated every month. It is a set of monthly sales amounts by products. A new product has been recently added to the source data and I can see it has been reflected in the Power Query and the corresponding tab in Power Pivot. However, the pivot table cannot include the sales amount of the new product after being refreshed. May I have your help to know what the most likely reason for this error is and how may I fix it?

Thank you very much in advance!

The entire file is not created by me. I just recently took over the responsibility of managing this report and found this error. I firstly checked the Power Pivot and Power Query and data shown there was all right. I simply don't understand how then the pivot table is not refreshing and reflecting the correct data. The pivot table settings have also been checked and it is correct too - correct items have been selected.

Comment: Look for a filter in the PowerPivot if you are sure the data exists in the PowerQuery last step

Comment: Also try right-clicking anywhere in the pivot and select refresh.